# MSSQL: Reference Main Query Case Result from Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, case

having a main query grouped on multiple conditions, one of them being the result of a case expression, i want to write a subquery to add a column to my resultset. this subquery has to be grouped on the same conditions. how to connect sub- and main query based on the result of the case expression?

My setup is so odd because i try to implement a median calculation in sql server 2008. It would work fine if it was not for the grouping on the case expression in the main query.

Update regarding the comments:

The Problem is that i have to make the subquery work on the same set of data as the main query. I am trying this by doing the same grouping and by connecting them in the WHERE clause.

But how to do a WHERE clause like

```
WHERE
subquery.property1 = mainquery.property1 // works
AND
CASE WHEN (subquery.A>subquery.B) THEN 'C' ELSE 'D' = CASE WHEN (mainquery.A>mainqueryB) THEN 
'C' ELSE 'D' // i dont know how to do this properly
```

Is it fine like this or do you really want the full query? Im hesistant because it is very large and confusing.

Update2:
Using a CTE worked fine. Wrote the data to the CTE with a new column containing the CASE result, then did all further selects on the CTE, making that column one of the where conditions.

Comment: Post the main query and sub query.

Comment: Your question provides no opportunity for anyone to really help, other than saying "use a correlation clause".

Comment: Without seeing your query, you'll probably either need to repeat the `CASE` expression or refactor with a CTE.

Comment: @DanGuzman: Using CTE is an interesting approach. I could just write the dataset, including the CASE result, to a CTE and then do a subquery on this i guess. Looks promising.